# Showing content in popup in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, ajax

Like [Modal Frame API](http://drupal.org/project/modalframe) in Drupal 6, is there a similar solution to load content in popup(without page refresh) in Drupal 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at

- [Modal Forms (with ctools)](http://drupal.org/project/modal_forms)
- [Colorbox](http://drupal.org/project/colorbox)
- [Lightbox2](http://drupal.org/project/lightbox2)

to name a few.  There are probably more out there, but one of those should do what you want.